# Procedure to write and execute custom queries for Visual Studio Team Services(VSTS) using Work Item Query Language(wiql)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, wiql

I wanted to extract data from VSTS using "WIQL" and do some reporting with that data.
1) Could someone please let me know if its is possible to use "WIQL" in PowerShell? If so, please let me know on where i can find the some samples or demos for this?

2) Also, are there any other client tools which support "WIQL" to make custom querying to VSTS. If so, please let me know where i can find some demo or some samples with respect to this?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: @starain..yes. I marked it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use WIQL in PowerShell, the easy way is that you could call [Work Item Query REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql) by using PowerShell.

For example:

```
$vstsAccount = "XX"
$projectName = "XX"
$user = ""
$token = "personal access token"
Function QueryWorkItem{



# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

# Construct the REST URL to obtain Build ID
$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).visualstudio.com/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0"


$body = "{
    'query':'Select [System.Id],[System.Title] From WorkItems Where [System.Id] = 123'
}"

# Invoke the REST call and capture the results (notice this uses the PATCH method)
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body

Write-Output ("work item title: '$($result.WorkItems[0].URL)'")

    }

    QueryWorkItem
```

More information, you can refer to [this](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/) article.

For secondly issue, you can build an application by yourself, such as console application with C# language.

1. Install [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package
2. Simple C# code

：

```
 var u = new Uri("https://XXX.visualstudio.com");
                VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("user name", "password")));
                var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
                var workitemClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

                var result = workitemClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.Wiql() { Query= "Select [System.Id],[System.Title] From WorkItems Where [System.Id] = 123" },"Scrum2015").Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result.WorkItems.First().Url);
```

Update 1:

The TFS/VSTS SDK or extend SDK can be used in PowerShell. For example:

```
if((Get-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
}
$Tfs2015AssembliesPath="[vs Installation path]\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$Tfs2015AssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
Function GetWorkItems{
    param([string]$teamProjectName,[string]$address)
    $credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]")
    $tfsCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection((New-Object System.URI($address)))
    $wis = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
    $wiqlQuery = "SELECT [System.ID], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'Scrum2015' AND  [State] = 'New' AND  [System.WorkItemType] in ('Bug','User Story')  ORDER BY [System.ID]";
    $witCollection = $wis.Query($wiqlQuery);

# add logical to export to excel.
    Foreach($witItem in $witCollection)
        {

            Write-Host $witItem.Title
        }
}
GetWorkItems "[project name]" "[tfs/vsts address]"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing some idea on how to write wiql in Powershell.

Comment: @starain..I tried the above code in Powershell, but i noticed that the data is not extracted to powershell but instead it is posted to an Url.              (1) Is there any way to extract the data into a powershell object and perform some operations on that object?  I wanted to extract work item list(like list of bugs, epics etc.) of a particular team project into a .CSV or .XLS file. Is this possible?

Comment: @Srini33 Yes, it is possible, I updated my answer, you can check it. By the way, if you have additional issue or question that not related to original issue directly, you can open a new thread.

Comment: @Srini33 If my solution helps you to solve your issue/question, you can mark it as answer.